# Looking for a RESTful or SOAP pipeline between WordPress and InterWoven TeamSite

Tags: wordpress, rest, soap, rss, teamsite

I've been Googling my brains out trying see if there's a simple way to bridge content to and from WordPress to and from TeamSite. I'm coming at this from the perspective of a WordPress developer.

I see in the book "The Definitive Guide to Interwoven TeamSite" (http://bit.ly/d3z4wI) mention of objects for the Interwoven LiveSite product:

- com.interwoven.livesite.external.impl.RSS
- com.interwoven.livesite.external.impl.SOAP

If I understand the above objects correctly, these allow me to instantiate objects of these data types, which after populating them via various method calls, allow me to render content using com.interwoven.livesite.external.ExternalCall ... but I'm not sure. Nor do I think this approach provides me the 2-way street I seek.

As it stands now, from my limited understanding, it appears that the least path of resistance is deploying Interwoven's LiveSite with the existing TeamSite implementation so content can be both consumed and rendered via RSS ... an channel which WordPress can produce and consume; the latter with plugins such as wp-o-matic and/or feedpress.

So the question is, does anyone out there have experience with a SOAP or RESTful API approach to InterWoven's TeamSite? If so, can I get some direction on documentation? Or is the addition of LiveSite + RSS the most feasible 2-way channel?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a AtomPub/NewsML based integration between Teamsite 6.7 and a video management system a year ago. I used a simple Perl/CGI approach because the client was using the Perl libs, not the Java API to Teamsite.

(BTW: the book is not in general a good one. Try the Interwoven (now Autonomy) developer forums instead)

Comment: Dean, feel free to contact me in private for details.